# x264_coeff_last64_sse2

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, x264, libx264

The x264 lib is crashing on Windows as always. Now, I'm trying to fix it, and I don't understand one thing. In the code we can see only the function signature:

```
int x264_coeff_last64_sse2( dctcoef *dct );
```

But, there is no implementation in *.h, *.c or *.asm source. How is that possible???

(The function is called and it crashed, so it has to be linked in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are being a little tricky :) It's actually defined as a macro in `quant.c` line 356 with my git checkout.

Here is the definition:

```
#define last(num)\
static int x264_coeff_last##num( dctcoef *l )\
{\
    int i_last = num-1;\
    while( i_last >= 0 && l[i_last] == 0 )\
        i_last--;\
    return i_last;\
}
```

**EDIT :** I think this is assembly code you were looking for are lines (1317-1363) in `x264\common\x86\quant-a.asm`:

```
%ifndef ARCH_X86_64
cglobal coeff_last64, 1, 5-mmsize/16
    pxor m2, m2
    LAST_MASK 16, r2d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF* 32, r4d
    LAST_MASK 16, r3d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF* 48, r4d
    shl r3d, 16
    or  r2d, r3d
    xor r2d, -1
    jne .secondhalf
    LAST_MASK 16, r1d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF* 0, r4d
    LAST_MASK 16, r3d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF*16, r4d
    shl r3d, 16
    or  r1d, r3d
    not r1d
    BSR eax, r1d, 0x1f
    RET
.secondhalf:
    BSR eax, r2d, 0x1f
    add eax, 32
    RET
%else
cglobal coeff_last64, 1,4
    pxor m2, m2
    LAST_MASK 16, r1d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF* 0
    LAST_MASK 16, r2d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF*16
    LAST_MASK 16, r3d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF*32
    LAST_MASK 16, r0d, r0+SIZEOF_DCTCOEF*48
    shl r2d, 16
    shl r0d, 16
    or  r1d, r2d
    or  r3d, r0d
    shl r3,  32
    or  r1,  r3
    not r1
    BSR rax, r1, 0x3f
    RET
%endif
%endmacro

%ifndef ARCH_X86_64
INIT_MMX mmx2
COEFF_LAST
%endif
INIT_XMM sse2
COEFF_LAST
INIT_XMM sse2, lzcnt
COEFF_LAST
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I believe that's the one called when you exclude the asm usage. The problematic one is written in asm (at least I assume so). And, it has an sse2 suffix.

Comment: Hm, if this is it... what's the relation between x264_coeff_last64_sse2() and coeff_last64?

Comment: One more thing... the debugger is not stopping in that asm code... What are the chances that we are looking at the wrong source?

Comment: It's certainly a possibility :) Do you happen to know where it's stopping, or have the local assembly where it's stopping?

Comment: Actually, there is one more important thing debugging related... In debug build with asm optimizations I get grey video. All frames are grey. That same release build crashes. Without asm optimizations everything works (I fixed some Windows related bugs) in both, debug and release. Ffmpeg guys are having major trouble writing code for Windows....

Comment: Stack was corrupted and show incorrect values. Still have no ide why, but you provided a correct answer. Thnx!!!